# db2pd -stack all has not output

Tags: db2

I ran db2pd -stack all on DB2 v9.7 running on RHEL 5.5 but there is not any outcome in db2inst1/sqllib/db2dump.

I suppose there should be some *.stack.txt files populated in folder FODC

Answer (score 0):

You probably did not run the db2pd as the instance owner. db2pd -stack sends POSIX signal (probably -3) to the main process. Signals from other users get silently discarded. The files will be written to DIAGPATH (db2 get dbm cfg|grep DIAGPATH).

Other possible reason is that the DB2 waits for lock before it can produce the stack trace. On a busy server this has on several versions caused a hard process hang so IBM has bugfixed the locking several times. It is possible that it can not get the lock required for producing the stack trace. In any event that is a bug and you should open PMR.

Comment: I did use the instance owner to run the command, your second guess might be the reason, but I need to confirm that.Thanks any way.